# How do I pull over info from google sheets into a dropdown menu in forms that will update itself every minute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, google-sheets-macros

I am setting up a trivia game through google sheets/forms.
I have a google form that makes a team enter in their team name and submit.
This then goes back to a google sheet with time stamps.
I want these responses to then be pulled into a drop down menu for my next 18 questions of trivia through google forms. Using the form ranger in google forms it will only update every hour or manually. I am trying to write a code that will update itself every minute or so.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in Google Apps Script

```
function changeForm() {
  var form = FormApp.openById("enter your form id here");
  var items = form.getItems();
  //get form id from inspect element at <input id=???>
  var question1 = form.getItemById('question id').asListItem();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your sheet id");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var answer = sheet.getRange(1, 2, row).getValues(); //range of answer
  question1.setTitle("title")
           .setRequired(true) //true or false
           .setChoiceValues(answer);
}
```

Then, save your project and go to [Your project in Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/home/my).

Click at your project.

Click three dots button, and choose "Triggers".

Click "Add Trigger".

Set your function name.

Set "Select event source" is "Time-driven"

Set your time to trigger